# Disable/Enable logs showing up in terminal

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-terminal

I am working with a Windows server which was configured by some colleagues which have since left the company. The console is configured in a way that very extensive logs are shown in the terminal (both cmd and powershell) after each command. While I understand the behavior and am quite sure that it is was turned on by a former college I cannot figure out how to turn it off/modify it. Does anyone know where this can be changed?
E.g. If I start VS Code from the cmd by typing `code .` It shows the following:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Projekts>code .

C:\Users\myuser\Projekts>
[main 2022-08-08T11:08:28.087Z] update#setState idle
[main 2022-08-08T11:08:40.057Z] Starting extension host with pid 21316 (fork() took 155 ms).
[main 2022-08-08T11:08:40.229Z] Starting extension host with pid 26136 (fork() took 152 ms).
[main 2022-08-08T11:08:46.352Z] Enabling inspect port on extension host with pid 26136.
[main 2022-08-08T11:08:58.103Z] update#setState checking for updates
[main 2022-08-08T11:08:58.139Z] update#setState idle
```

The terminal is not blocked, but (of course) new logs keep coming and if the terminal is closed VS code closes as well.

So I assume that there is a config file somewhere but I cannot find out where etc.

Comment: I can't seemingly find the docs on this at the moment, but those logs are from VsCode itself. It was started from the console, so that console is vscode's stdout.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but the thing is that is happens for all programs. So I assume that there is a global configuration set somewhere.